# Flask - redirect url_for Error

Tags: python, flask

Am having errors thrown in my flask application for the below Code.

```
@@app.route('/')
.....

return redirect(url_for('nextPage'),id=DBTable.id)


@app.route('/<path:id>')
@login_required
def nextPage(id):
return render_template('page2.html')               

Error - 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing.py", line 1607, in build
raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method)
BuildError: ('nextPage', {}, None)
<SocketIOServer fileno=116 address=0.0.0.0:5000>: Failed to handle request:
request = POST /landingPage HTTP/1.1 from ('127.0.0.1', 50287)
application = <flask.app.Flask object at 0x0000000002643B70>
```

Kindly help me with the above issue

Comment: Try adding '/' at the end of route as @app.route('/<path:id>/')

Answer (score 6):

Besides all the obvious syntax errors, the problem should be resolved by placing the arguments that you pass to the route within the `url_for` block.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    # ...
    return redirect(url_for('nextPage', id=DBTable.id))

@app.route('/<id>')
def nextPage(id):
    # ...
    return render_template('page2.html')
```

Comment: thanks for the response Teisman, but still am seeing same error after changing this.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Are you sure it is the same error? I ask this because it works on my machine. It never hurts to move to simpler code when debugging. Since we aren't using `id` for the moment, try filling in a dummy value, such as 'test', so that it becomes `return redirect(url_for('nextPage', id="test"))`, and check if the same error is thrown again.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this code

```
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return redirect(url_for('random', id="blah blah"))

@app.route('/<id>')
def random(id):
    return id

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and tell me if you're having any error.